# Force default index page in browser

Tags: html, indexing, webserver

usually when an index page cannot be found, the browser automatically generates a page that shows the content of the current folder. Is it possible to force that generated index page even though a website has an index page?

My goal is to browse the files of a webserver that allows anyone to do so by accessing the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the browser that is generating that page, it is the server, and that directory listing behavior is typically configured within the web server.  There is no client-side solution to this problem.  You would need to configure what page, if any, is served up in response to a request which does not correspond to a specific resource URL.